# How would I insert a message.delete command into this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I am making a purge command for my bot, and I want the bot to delete the embed it sends after 2s. I am currently using discord.js, and I also can use node's ms plugin. So whenever I try something like

```
    try {
      await message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
        .then(messages =>message.channel.send(purgeEmbed))
    }catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      message.channel.send(issuePurgeEmbed);
    }
     var message = await message.channel.send(purgeEmbed);
     message.delete({timeout: 2000});
  }
}
```

It works, sort of. The result is the bot sending 2 messages and deleting one after 2s. So then I tried

```
    try {
      await message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
        .then(messages =>message.channel.send(purgeEmbed))
        .then(message.delete({timeout: 2000})
    }catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      message.channel.send(issuePurgeEmbed);
    }
  }
}
```

and that didn't work either. I am relatively new to coding, so it might just be something that I haven't learned yet. If there is an easier way to do it with node's ms plugin, that would work too. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should remove the try catch and await part, and use the `promise.then(...).catch(...)` syntax.

Comment: There's no need to use `.then()` if you aren't using the return values from the promises. Try using simple sequencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code with simpler sequencing thanks to Elitezen's and Shivam's. I edited the code so it now states:

```
await message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched);
    var message = await message.channel.send(purgeEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err))
    message.delete({timeout: 2000 }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Thanks for the help you two :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
await message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched).then(setTimeout(() => {
    message.delete().catch(err => console.log(err));
},2000));
```